# OutOfMemoryException raised when loading Pictures from folder

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Why am I receiving an `OutOfMemoryException` when I try to load files from my Pictures folder? There are no more than about 20 pictures in there (including sub-directories).

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dynamic files = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures));
    if(files != null)
    {
        foreach(var file in files)
        {
            PictureBox box = new PictureBox();
            box.Image = Image.FromFile(file);
            box.Height = 250;
            box.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

            canvas.Controls.Add(box);
        }
    }
}
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred
>   in System.Drawing.dll

I'm guessing there's a better way to be writing this?

> Additional information: Out of memory.

Comment: Did you make sure that there are only pictures in that folder?

Comment: Why do you use "dynamic" for the files variable?

Comment: How large are the pictures? Maybe it's possible you're actually out of memory? I think resizing the box won't shrink the actual image in memory.

Comment: @TheMotivation Yep. I did make sure there are only Pictures in that folder and all its sub-directories. I'm kinda OCD in that way.

Comment: okay, still I would recommend to check each file before loading it into a picturebox ;)

Comment: @HåkanFahlstedt Because I'm not allowed to use it at work. So in my personal projects, I tend to use whatever the hell I want, so long as it actually works.

Comment: @sdf the pictures are no more than 1mb each. I have 8GB ram. How else would I load pictures onto the form then if this is what's going to happen?

Comment: @spike.y your file size does not neccesarily correlate with how much memory a picture takes, as an example with png crush/black & white image you can get a 4000x2500 file to be about 0.5k on disk, when loaded into memory it will probably take 4000x2500x4 bytes (regular ARGB)

Comment: I just opened up a finished project I wrote last week, and the exact same code is in there to load pictures from the same folder. It still works. Not sure why, now.

Comment: @TheMotivation you were right. There _is_ a file in the Pictures folder which is not an image file. The file is `Desktop.ini`, and the reason I said there were no files other than images is because I checked the `Show hidden files` option and there were none. Upon looking more closely VS says that Image.FromFile is trying  to load a Desktop.ini file (which doesn't even appear when the `Show hidden files` option in explorer is checked).

Comment: So this solves your problem? I'll post it as an answer if so.

Comment: @TheMotivation it sure did. Thank you very much. I should've done a file-type check to begin with. Disappointed in myself right now.